# How to convert input file .pdf in string Base64?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html5-canvas, base64

How to get Base64 from an input file type:pdf?. i´m trying convert a file .pdf in string base64 with JavaScript.
Example:

```
var base64 = funtionconvertBase64(file);                                           

function funtionconvertBase64(file){                                              
  ....
  ....
return stringbase64            
}
```

Comment: What is `file`? Where is your code running?

Comment: what is the example supposed to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the file using the FileReader.

```
<input id="loadFile" type="file" onchange="readAsBase64()" />

<script type="text/javascript">

function readAsBase64() {

    var files = document.getElementById("loadFile").files;
    if (files.length > 0) {

        var fileToLoad = files[0];
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        var base64File;
        // Reading file content when it's loaded
        fileReader.onload = function(event) {
            base64File = event.target.result;
            // base64File console
            console.log(base64File);
        };

        // Convert data to base64
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }
}
</script>
```